# Why do my loops stop early when iterating through and array

Tags: java, arrays

So I am trying to iterate through a 4 by 3 array of objects and set the value of each object according to user input, but I've run into a problem where the iteration through the array stop at 6 instead of the total 12. I've tried a few way of writing the iterators but they always fail. This is the code.

```
Card[][] field = new Card[3][2];
    void setvals(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int row= 0; row < field.length; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < field[row].length; col++) {
                String input = scanner.nextLine();
                field[row][col] = new Card();
                field[row][col].makeCard(input);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have also tried <= instead of < but then it gives me array index out of bounds. I have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: You are creating a 3x2 array, what makes you think there should be 12 things in it?

Comment: Ummmm, field is 3 by 2, not 4 by 3. Are you confusing array sizes with array indexes?

Comment: Misconception on your end. You dont have a 4x3 array. Yours is 3x2 ... so 6 elements. So please: just delete the question and move on ;-)

Comment: Change this `Card[][] field = new Card[3][2];` to `Card[][] field = new Card[4][3];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the array:

```
Card[][] field = new Card[3][2];
```

You want the array to be `4 x 3`, then set the dimensions as so:

```
Card[][] field = new Card[4][3];
```

The reason your code is not working, is since you currently have a `2 x 3` array, evaluating to 6 iterations. A `4 x 3` array would evaluate to 12 iterations, as you want.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had originally but my teacher told me that it was actually 3X2 because arrays start for 0. I realize how dumb that sounds now and also realize I should take his advice with a grain of salt.

Comment: @LightningJimmyJoeJohnson If you found this answer correct, then please mark it correct by clicking the green checkmark icon next to the answer, to mark it correct. This is to ensure that future askers of this question, do not ask it again, and can easily see that the solution worked for you.

Comment: Yep I forgot stack overflow kept telling me I needed to wait a few minutes before marking the check, I just forgot about it after a while. Whoops

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> So I am trying to iterate through a 4 by 3 array of objects...

And here is your array: `Card[][] field = new Card[3][2];`.

That is not a 4x3 array. It is a 3x2 array, which means there should be 6 iterations in your loop, which is what is happening. There is no error here.